# What is the meaning of "fallar"?

Tags: translation-check

"Sum ut nox
Et fallar mox"
My conversation partner showed me a poem he's written and I couldn't understand the meaning of the future passive form "fallar". He told me to use the poetic license, but I didn't really understand what he meant by "fallar".
I know that the passive form of the verb fallere means "to be mistaken, to deceive one's self", and when it's used absolute, it means "to be unseen". Since he's comparing himself to the night, I think that the absolute form makes more sense. I'm not saying he's wrong(poetic license) yet I've always found this verb hard to translate.

Comment: Maybe you should ask your friend. We can't read his mind any more than you can.

Comment: I really asked him, but he told me "think whatever you want."Maybe I should edit and ask if "fallar" makes any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this question, of course, is that if you asked about a line from Horace or Ovid, then we'd know there must be some sort of solution; but since the author is an unknown contemporary of ours, he could also simply have made a mistake. His evasive answers to your well-justified questions would support this variant.

Also, your own terminology seems to be a little confused; you write that *fallere*, “when used absolute,” has the meaning “to be unseen” – this is true, but concerns the active voice.

However, there is a pretty strange poetic usage, in which *fallere* means (to quote [Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfallo)) “to cause any thing (space, time, etc.) not to be observed or felt, to lighten any thing difficult, or to appease, silence any thing disagreeable, to beguile.” An example is: *medias fallunt sermonibus horas* (Ovid, M. 8, 652), which means, roughly, “they made the intervening hours not felt (by their guests) with conversations,” although one should keep in mind that it *literally* means they fooled the hours—poetic license indeed.

It is possible that your correspondent had this usage in mind. In the passive this would become “I will be made (or become) unobserved, unfelt.” However, it would be an unusual and questionable application of a rare and already somewhat convoluted metaphor. And, of course, it is just speculation on my part.

Comment: Sebastian, I believe you understood him better the me! This verb has very distinctive meanings. Since I was trying to find an equivalent in Portuguese, I couldn’t see. The problem is the passive voice! I'm really sure he used "fallar " as a deponent verb. He will be(come)unseen. I'm gonna beg him to tell the real meaning!